# run a function when the length of input field reaches to its limit

Tags: javascript

I have following code in my view file:

```
<input class="form-control centered" name="Form[a_3]" id="Form_a_3" type="text">
```

I used inputmask to impliment validation for this input field:

```
$("#Form_p_3").inputmask({mask:"999999",clearMaskOnLostFocus: true});
```

I need to run following function `$('#ABlockForm_p_3').keyup(function(){.... }),`when the length is equal to 6. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the length of the value with `val().length`.

```js
$('#ABlockForm_p_3').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length >= 6) {
     // this function
   alert('It is now 6 chars long');
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ABlockForm_p_3" />
```

Comment: If you look at input mask code, you will see that I implimented max length of input field

Comment: if i wrote you code, it would alert even the length is not equal to 6

Comment: Because of this code: $("#Form_p_3").inputmask({mask:"999999",clearMaskOnLostFocus: true});

Comment: Then provide a fiddle that replicates the exact issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
$('#ABlockForm_p_3').keyup(function(){
if($('#ABlockForm_p_3').val().length==6)
{
//your code
}
});
```

Comment: This will not work if he didn't set the maxlength attribute to the input field and someone pastes a 7 characters long string into it. After that he could go on typing forever.

Comment: agreed but the question says "when the length is equal to 6." so maybe @phpdev wants the code to run only when the length is 6.